# Is there a formal XML coding standard for readability?

Tags: xml

I'm a contract programmer in a shop where I'll be supplying their first Android and first .Net WPF products.  After I'm done they'll have to maintain it, but because it's their first they have no existing standards or conventions for XML (and XAML) coding style and don't have an opinion.

I know XML was originally conceived to be more for machine consumption than human readability, but the reality is that both Android's XML for its layout/UI and WPF's XAML often require lots of hand-editing and reading.

At other shops I've followed existing conventions but I have to admit that for my own personal stuff I haven't been all that consistent over the years.   I've seen countless different styles of indenting, whitespace, comments, closing elements, etc e.g., some people put all the attributes on the same line as the opening element tag, some people start the attributes on a new line, some people use one line per attribute, etc, etc.

So **my question is**:  does there exist a formal standard or guidelines by a standards body (W3C?) or a major company for coding readable XML, and if so what is it?

I'm only posting this because after extensive Googling I didn't see one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not such thing as a styling guideline in [a language specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-conformance).

Spec defines well-formated document only in terms of document structure, with no regard to white spaces in between elements.

Regarding comments, there are placed in between `<!--` and `-->` (see [section 2.5 of XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments)). If you want to use characters which could be mistaken by the parser to be markup, you can use `CDATA` section as well.

If I were you, I would just pick some notation and be consistent through your project. Android 's Eclipse plugin is using some specific style of XML formatting, so you can just stick with that.

Comment: Thanks kamituel.  I agree that W3C doesn't seem to have one -  I was hoping that maybe some large company or some open source group had presented one.  That way I can include a reference to it in the documentation I leave the client.

Comment: @user316117 -- It would be interesting to see that, although even if some large enterprise uses such a standard internally, it would have to be somehow recommended by W3C (or other standarization body) to be widely accepted. Never seen something like that, though.